# How to use custom plugin in maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, xslt

I created one custom plugin in maven. So when run this project then automatically created related one JAR file. So now i created one more project in maven in this project how to use that jar file in the pom.xml file. Is there any possible to use already existing jars in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of what you're getting at- my understanding is that you wrote a plugin that you now want to use in a separate project.  In order to do this, you would add the custom plugin to your  section in the new project.  It will resolve this the same way it does all plugins.  You also need to deploy the plugin to whatever pluginRepository you're using.

For example, I have a plugin, which is defined in its pom as:

```
<groupId>org.mine</groupId>
<artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin>
```

which is what it seems you already have.

Then, run mvn deploy.

In the project you want to use the plugin is, add to your pom:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mine</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

Finally, make sure you have the repository you deployed to set up in your pom.xml in the  tag.